# Case Expression Comparing ColumnName lookup exists and ColumnName is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a case expression that looks for all the columns in my table with a ColumnName like '%45-%' AND where ColumnName like '45-' is not null.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN (SELECT [name] 
               FROM   tempdb.sys.columns 
               WHERE  [object_id] = Object_id(N'tempdb..#temp') 
                      AND [name] LIKE '45-%') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS x 
FROM   #temp
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

==============================================================

Adding table for output reference

```
name    45-AB    72    36    NewColumn
Dan     null     null  null  0
Steve   1        null  null  1
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do a JOIN instead.

Comment: How would you join? I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

As long as

```
SELECT [name] 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp') and [name] like '45-%'
```

returns more than one value it won't work.
With subqueries, if its result is compared to a value (is null or equal), it has to return one value

try this:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN exists(SELECT [name] 
               FROM   tempdb.sys.columns 
               WHERE  [object_id] = Object_id(N'tempdb..#temp') 
                      AND [name] LIKE '45-%') THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS x 
FROM   #temp
```

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to 'loop'? Moreover, do the comparison for every value where value like '45-%' The issue is I'm using dynamic sql to create columns. As such, I don't know how many column headers will have the conditional value.

Comment: Any form of looping is (almost) always a bad idea in an RDBMS, @dcrowley01 . RDBMS' work in sets, programs work iteratively.

Comment: Update: that solution will always return 1 as the the columns always exist, but I need to know when they exist if they have a value or are null.

Comment: if the result is null, it won't be considered as "exists" therefore the else pat will be active

Comment: the expression above returns 1 for all rows in column x, I think because the column 45-% will always exist. When 45-% is null in the row though, x should equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will generate (and execute if you uncomment the EXEC line) sql code that will return the field names of the table and a 1 if the column contains at least 1 non null value or a 0 if all values in the field are NULL.

You can add your where columnname like '45-%' to the below code so it will only evaluate/return those fields.

```
select 1 as '45-1', 2 as '45-2', null as '45-3', 4  as '45-4' into #temp

DECLARE @tb nvarchar(512) = N'tempdb..#temp';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N''

 SELECT @sql += 'select ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''' as ColumnName, case when (select top 1 ''Not Null'' from tempdb..#temp where ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' is not null ) = ''Not Null'' Then 1 else 0 end as IsColumnNull
Union '
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);


    set @sql =  left(@sql,len(@sql) - 5)

    select @sql
    --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Juan, This appears really close or I'm not editing it to complete my task. I don't have much experience with dynamic sql. Although what returns from this is a column of header columns and then a column of whether or not it was null. I'm trying to return my table with my column names horizontally with an additional column that looks to see if that value was null. Does that make sense? **added table above for clarity**